# MechanicalTurk.XMLParseError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, mechanicalturk

I'm trying to create a external question with the Amazon's Mechanical Turk SDK (mturk).

Following this guide: http://alex.nisnevich.com/blog/2013/05/23/rolling_your_own_mechanical_turk_form.html

I created an xml file, and I'm including it in the createHit call under 'question', however I keep getting this error:

> Amazon::WebServices::Util::ValidationException: AWS.MechanicalTurk.XMLParseError
>   from /Users/*/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@*/gems/mturk-1.9.0/lib/amazon/webservices/mturk/mechanical_turk_error_handler.rb:143:in `block in validateResponse'

I was getting this error passing the xml in as a string and thought using File.read would fix it, but since I'm getting the same error I'm at a loss.

```
xml_path = "#{Rails.root.to_s}/app/assets/turk/question.xml"

mturk.createHIT(
  :Title => 'title test',
  :Description => 'desc. test',
  :MaxAssignments => 10,
  :Reward => { :Amount => 0.01, :CurrencyCode => 'USD' },
  :Question => File.read(xml_path),
  :Keywords => 'KEYWORDS test'
)
```

**question.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ExternalQuestion xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurk/2014-08-15/AWSMechanicalTurkRequester.xsd">
    <ExternalURL>"google.com"</ExternalURL>
    <FrameHeight>200</FrameHeight>
</ExternalQuestion>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your ExternalURL is wrong. Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ExternalQuestion xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2006-07-14/ExternalQuestion.xsd">
  <ExternalURL>https://www.google.com</ExternalURL>
  <FrameHeight>200</FrameHeight>
</ExternalQuestion>
```

See [External Question schema](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_ExternalQuestionArticle.html)

**Edit:**

I just changed the xmlns to "http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2006-07-14/ExternalQuestion.xsd" and it ran for me.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Definitely learned something new (https required).  Unfortunately I'm still getting the error.

Comment: I also tried building the xml like this: 

xml = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|
 xml.ExternalQuestion('xmlns' => 'http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurk/2014-08-15/AWSMechanicalTurkRequester.xsd') {
  xml.ExternalUrl "https://google.com"
  xml.FrameHeight 200
 }
end